# Can't remove white space between header and navbar when using Materializecss

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am using the materializecss framework from materializecss.com. I have a simple image that I place above the navbar from materializecss and there is a small white space. I checked the source and there is no margin, padding or border at all. The space goes away if I put the navbar above the image so I am not sure what the problem is.

```
<img id="header" src="/public/images/header.gif" alt="Header"/>
  <nav class="grey darken-4">
    <div id="navbar" class="nav-wrapper">
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I am not using any other css besides the materializecss css file. Any ideas? I don't think that css has any margins anywhere as I don't see it when viewing the source for any of the elements.

Edit: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0tL9up9s/ The list elements aren't appearing because I haven't copied over the javascript but you can still see the white space between the image and the navbar.

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem that’s occurring. By reproducing the problem in a way that we can verify it, it will be easier for us to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think it has to do with the fact that the image is `display:inline` and therefore has dimensions that include the `line-height`.

Setting your image to `display: block` will correct this issue.

CSS

```
#header { display:block; }
```

Or (HTML)

```
<img id="header" src="/public/images/header.gif" style="display:block" alt="Header"/>
```

Your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0tL9up9s/1/

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `html {line-height: 0}` to the end of the materialize.css file seems to fix the problem. I have no idea if it will break any other functionality though, so be careful.

http://jsfiddle.net/8ppt5zou/1/

Comment: Yea this seems to work great. Not sure if it will break anything else though but I will update if I find something. Is there a way to make this change only applicable for the navbar? I tried adding it to the div and it messed up the list items.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="header" style="display:block;" src="http://www.thousandwonders.net/covers/89/Bryce.Canyon.National.Park.jpg" alt="Header" >

<nav class="grey darken-4">
    <div id="navbar" class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Skills</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```